# Why my spring transaction manager for jdbc is not working?

Tags: java, spring, spring-transactions

I have config the transaction manager for JDBC, but when I do this:

```
dao.insert(something);
throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
```

the transaction doesn't rollback

```
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />

<!-- define JDBC datasource by DBCP -->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ts" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="1234" />
    </bean>

    <!--  DataSourceTransactionManager for jdbc -->
    <bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="fooDao" class="com.oolong.dao.FooDao">
        <property name="dstm" ref="txManager"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="fooService" class="com.oolong.service.DefaultFooService">
        <property name="fooDao" ref="fooDao"></property>
    </bean>

    <tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="txManager">
        <tx:attributes>
            <tx:method name="get*" read-only="true" propagation="REQUIRED"/>
            <tx:method name="*" read-only="false"  propagation="REQUIRED" 
                rollback-for="java.lang.RuntimeException"/>
        </tx:attributes>
    </tx:advice>

    <aop:config>
        <aop:pointcut id="fooServiceOperation" expression="execution(* com.oolong.service.FooService.*(..))"/>
        <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="fooServiceOperation"/>
    </aop:config>
```

It's a simple example, a DefaultFooService implements the FooService interface.
The service has a dao, FooDao, has a method will insert a record into a table.

When I run the code. The transaction haven't been created! of course can't roll back.

FooService interface

```
package com.oolong.service;

import com.oolong.model.Foo;

public interface FooService {

    Foo getFoo(String fooName);

    Foo getFoo(String fooName, String barName);

    void insertFoo(Foo foo);

    void updateFoo(Foo foo);
}
```

DefaultFooService.java

```
package com.oolong.service;

import com.oolong.dao.FooDao;
import com.oolong.model.Foo;

public class DefaultFooService implements FooService {

    private FooDao fooDao;

    public void setFooDao(FooDao fooDao) {
        this.fooDao = fooDao;
    }

    public Foo getFoo(String fooName) {

        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    public Foo getFoo(String fooName, String barName) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    public void insertFoo(Foo foo) {
        fooDao.insert();
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    public void updateFoo(Foo foo) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}
```

FooDao.java

```
package com.oolong.dao;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager;

public class FooDao {

    private DataSourceTransactionManager dstm;

    public void setDstm(DataSourceTransactionManager dstm) {
        this.dstm = dstm;
    }

    public void insert() {
        try {
            DataSource ds = dstm.getDataSource();
            Connection conn = ds.getConnection();

            String sql = "insert into item (wid, answer, isCorrect, choiceWid) "
                    + "values ('1', '1', 1, '1')";

            Statement st = conn.createStatement();
            st.executeUpdate(sql);

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

AppContainer.java

```
public class AppContainer {

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
        ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/beans.xml", AppContainer.class);
        FooService fooService = (FooService) ctx.getBean("fooService");
        fooService.insertFoo(new Foo());
    }
}
```

The information log4j output before throw the UnsupportedOperationException:

```
Loaded NamespaceHandler mappings: {http://www.springframework.org/schema/p=org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.SimplePropertyNamespaceHandler, http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc=org.springframework.web.servlet.config.MvcNamespaceHandler, http://www.springframework.org/schema/util=org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.UtilNamespaceHandler, http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee=org.springframework.ejb.config.JeeNamespaceHandler, http://www.springframework.org/schema/websocket=org.springframework.web.socket.config.WebSocketNamespaceHandler, http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop=org.springframework.aop.config.AopNamespaceHandler, http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm=org.springframework.oxm.config.OxmNamespaceHandler, http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc=org.springframework.jdbc.config.JdbcNamespaceHandler, http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache=org.springframework.cache.config.CacheNamespaceHandler, http://www.springframework.org/schema/c=org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.SimpleConstructorNamespaceHandler, http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx=org.springframework.transaction.config.TxNamespaceHandler, http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms=org.springframework.jms.config.JmsNamespaceHandler, http://www.springframework.org/schema/task=org.springframework.scheduling.config.TaskNamespaceHandler, http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang=org.springframework.scripting.config.LangNamespaceHandler, http://www.springframework.org/schema/context=org.springframework.context.config.ContextNamespaceHandler}
Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator'
Creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator'
Eagerly caching bean 'org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator' to allow for resolving potential circular references
Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator'
Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@3224f60b: defining beans [org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,dataSource,txManager,fooDao,fooService,txAdvice,fooServiceOperation,org.springframework.aop.support.DefaultBeanFactoryPointcutAdvisor#0]; root of factory hierarchy
Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator'
Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'dataSource'
Creating instance of bean 'dataSource'
Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.aop.support.DefaultBeanFactoryPointcutAdvisor#0'
Creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.aop.support.DefaultBeanFactoryPointcutAdvisor#0'
Eagerly caching bean 'org.springframework.aop.support.DefaultBeanFactoryPointcutAdvisor#0' to allow for resolving potential circular references
Creating instance of bean 'fooServiceOperation'
Finished creating instance of bean 'fooServiceOperation'
Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.aop.support.DefaultBeanFactoryPointcutAdvisor#0'
Eagerly caching bean 'dataSource' to allow for resolving potential circular references
Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.aop.support.DefaultBeanFactoryPointcutAdvisor#0'
Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.aop.support.DefaultBeanFactoryPointcutAdvisor#0'
Finished creating instance of bean 'dataSource'
Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'txManager'
Creating instance of bean 'txManager'
Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.aop.support.DefaultBeanFactoryPointcutAdvisor#0'
Eagerly caching bean 'txManager' to allow for resolving potential circular references
Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'dataSource'
Invoking afterPropertiesSet() on bean with name 'txManager'
Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.aop.support.DefaultBeanFactoryPointcutAdvisor#0'
Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.aop.support.DefaultBeanFactoryPointcutAdvisor#0'
Finished creating instance of bean 'txManager'
Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'fooDao'
Creating instance of bean 'fooDao'
Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.aop.support.DefaultBeanFactoryPointcutAdvisor#0'
Eagerly caching bean 'fooDao' to allow for resolving potential circular references
Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'txManager'
Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.aop.support.DefaultBeanFactoryPointcutAdvisor#0'
Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.aop.support.DefaultBeanFactoryPointcutAdvisor#0'
Finished creating instance of bean 'fooDao'
Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'fooService'
Creating instance of bean 'fooService'
Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.aop.support.DefaultBeanFactoryPointcutAdvisor#0'
Eagerly caching bean 'fooService' to allow for resolving potential circular references
Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'fooDao'
Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.aop.support.DefaultBeanFactoryPointcutAdvisor#0'
Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.aop.support.DefaultBeanFactoryPointcutAdvisor#0'
Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'txAdvice'
Creating instance of bean 'txAdvice'
Eagerly caching bean 'txAdvice' to allow for resolving potential circular references
Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'txManager'
Creating instance of bean '(inner bean)#63021689'
Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.aop.support.DefaultBeanFactoryPointcutAdvisor#0'
Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.aop.support.DefaultBeanFactoryPointcutAdvisor#0'
Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.aop.support.DefaultBeanFactoryPointcutAdvisor#0'
Finished creating instance of bean '(inner bean)#63021689'
Invoking afterPropertiesSet() on bean with name 'txAdvice'
Finished creating instance of bean 'txAdvice'
Finished creating instance of bean 'fooService'
Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'txAdvice'
Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.aop.support.DefaultBeanFactoryPointcutAdvisor#0'
Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'lifecycleProcessor'
Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'fooService'
```

Comment: The error is thrown when you start the server or when you send the request to server after starting up.

Comment: The pointcut should be on DefaultFooService, AFAIK, not on FooService. But a much simpler way would be to use annotations for bean definitions and transactional beans/methods, autowiring, and Java config rather than XML.

Comment: @SachinSarawgi It's just a java project, no server, no request

Comment: @JBNizet First time, I put the pointcut on the DefaultFooService, it's not work.

Comment: What is the access specifier before the method inside which you are throwing the error message??

Comment: Post a minimal, complete example reproducing the problem. Two lines of code are not sufficient.

Comment: @SachinSarawgi  I add all log before the exception

Comment: @JBNizet I add all log before the exception

Comment: @Oolong could you please provide FoorServer insert method snippet.

Comment: @SachinSarawgi  I updated it, thanks.

Comment: @Oolong add public access specifier before the method, it will work.

Comment: @SachinSarawgi Which method? These methods all public.

Comment: @Oolong the method on which you want to support transaction behaviour.

Comment: @SachinSarawgi I want the DefaultFooService.insertFoo() to support the behaviour, but it already be public.

Comment: Read the javadoc of DataSourceTransactionManager. http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/DataSourceTransactionManager.html. It explains how you should get a transaction-scoped transaction. You'd better use JdbcTemplate, which does that, and more, for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see this:

> Application code is required to retrieve the JDBC Connection via
>   DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSource) instead of a standard Java
>   EE-style DataSource.getConnection() call. Spring classes such as
>   JdbcTemplate use this strategy implicitly.

thansk for @JB Nizet, @SachinSarawgi.

I should use the JdbcTemplate.